# Where does TDD coves in the conventional software development approch?

Tags: tdd, project

I am new to TDD. I have to build a project using TDD. I want to know if I have to create all the SRS and design before starting with TDD?

Comment: Software Requirements Specification

Answer (score 1):

Many people are using ATDD with TDD.  The Owner, BA should have the requirement.

Mostly the requirement is given in the form a Story.

Example: 
As a (some role)
I'd like to (some feature here)
so I can  (benefit/value of the feature here)

The dev team testers and business guy should have a meeting and "Talk" about each requirement.

then you come up with a what Done means.  below is a good syntax I often use to help come up with good testable definitions.

As "Role" should be able to see/do the following(input test):
Given (some_initial_condition(s))
When (evens(s)_occurs)
Then (ensure_some_outcome)

Edge Case (The maximum or minimum input which is expected to produce correct output)

From this you can have a good ideal how to set your unit test.

You might also want to use a tool like cucumber https://cukes.info/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not possible to do anyrhing without requirements, therefore the SRS is required anyway. If your software is agile enough, it should be easy to apply any change to SRS. Any change to requirements means changing both the code and tests.

The second part of the question is about design. It is a common misconception that no design is done in the agile development (and TDD as such). That means that, as in other kinds of SE development processes, design is done before going into implementation. And the architecture is done even before the design.

To quote [wikipedia's TDD design chapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Designing_for_testability) :

> Effective modular design yields components that share traits essential
>   for effective TDD.
>   * High Cohesion ensures each unit provides a set of related capabilities and makes the tests of those capabilities easier to maintain.
>   * Low Coupling allows each unit to be effectively tested in isolation.
>   * Published Interfaces restrict Component access and serve as contact points for tests, facilitating test creation and ensuring the highest fidelity between test and production unit configuration.

and :

> Scenario modeling can greatly facilitate the construction of TDD tests for a complex system.

So, the system is modeled, but with testability in mind, and we see in the above quote the characteristics of such system (High Cohesion and Low Coupling).